# How can i use cast companion library(CCL) ? Have integrated but not being able to connect to cast device

Tags: android, casting

I have already added the library in the project and also taking the reference of the **Cast-Video** tutorial and I was able to show the cast button if the device is in the same network ,but when I connect it does not connect.

Having a lot of trouble.I don't know whats the problem is. I **have registered** the app also in the developers site for cast device.